# angularjs custom directive with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angularjs and I don't know if this is possible and if possible how to implement it.
I want to create a custom directive with a controller that uses information passed to it through attributes. This is a non working example of what I want to implement:

The HTML should look like:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <custom-directive attr1="value1" attr2="value2"></custom-directive>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
   var app = angular.module('test', [ ]);
    app.directive("customDirective", function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: ???,
            controller: function(){
                console.log("print attributes value: " + attr1 + ", " +  attr2 );
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And the expect console output should be:

> > print attributes value: value1, value2

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In your directive you can define the scope objects (attributes) you want to access and use as follows:

```
app.directive("customDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {attr1: "=", attr2: "="},
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            console.log("print attributes value: " + attr.attr1 + ", " +  attr.attr2 );
        }
    };
```

There are different types of bindings you can use:

- = is for two-way binding
- @ simply reads the value (one-way binding)
- & is used to bind functions

See below link for more information:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Comment: When I try to execute your code I obtain the following error: _Error: scope is not defined_. I've tried to pass _scope_ as a parameter _controller: function(scope, element, attr){..}_ but doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, I have just updated my example, now it should work. I forgot to pass the "attr" to the link function and then access the attribute that way. Please note that I am using the link function for output and that it should be "restrict: 'E'" instead of "restrict = 'E'".

Answer (score 2):

Looking further I found this possible solution to my problem. It is very similar to the one proposed by Plunker with only slight changes in the syntax. This one works for me but I do not understand why the proposed by Plunker not.

```
app.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return {
        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                    console.log("Value: " + attributes.attr1 + attributes.attr2);
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Directives can get quite complex. Knowing your end goal would allow a better answer, but this is the simplest way to do what you're asking:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.directive("customDirective", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            console.log("print attributes value: " + attr.attr1 + ", " +  attr.attr2 );
        }
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKX9G5Qr8XTtzx1iTJNT?p=preview)

Comment: When I execute your code nothing appears in the console neither an error.

Comment: @narcispr What version of angular are you using? Did you try the Plunkr? That works...